# visual studio query, with a control parameter

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to get the following query to work however im not sure exactly how to declare the variable control in the query. The Cause is the control parameter

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) 
FROM         dist_reason
WHERE     (cause_group_cd = '%'Cause'%')
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can format code sections in your posts by selecting the code and pressing the little `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# (since it seems you want to call this from code), you would do so as follows:

```
string sqlStatement;

sqlStatement = string.format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dist_reason WHERE (cause_group_cd = '%{0}%')", Cause);
```

If you were doing this in SQL only, you would declare a variable and it would look like @Cause.  For example:

```
DECLARE @Cause NVARCHAR(50)

SET @Test = 'Test'

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM dist_reason
WHERE (cause_group_cd = '%' + @Cause + '%')
```

Comment: In c#, you would use SqlCommand and a parameter, NOT string.format. string.format is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, if 'cause' is from a non-sanitised source (i.e user input).

Comment: I was assuming that the variable was coming from a reliable source such as being built in the code.  You are correct, you wouldn't want to pull this directly from user input.

Comment: The danger with "... assuming that the variable was coming from a reliable source " is that situation might change at a later date, and open a hole. The fact that the search string is variable often means user specified.